# Однородные члены

Tags: пунктуация

Как здесь расставлять знаки препинания? Если "распорных усилий и скорости потока среды" - это одна пара однородных членов, а эта пара + "химического состава среды" - другая, то запятые не нужны. Или лучше убрать один союз "и" и поставить запятую?

Выбор материала, строительная длина и форма резинокордного компенсатора координируются индивидуально с учетом параметров среды: температуры, давления, осевых, боковых и угловых перемещений, распорных усилий и скорости потока среды и химического состава среды.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выбор материала, строительная длина и форма резинокордного компенсатора координируются индивидуально с учетом параметров среды: температуры, давления, осевых, боковых и угловых перемещений, распорных усилий, а также скорости потока и химического состава среды.